# How to test a service method that returns a model?

Tags: testing, phpunit

So I have a service method that modifies a model object

```
public function doSomething() {
    $model = new Model();

    // Modify the model with a bunch of private methods

    return $model;
}
```

If I want to test doSomething, I really only have $model to work with. And the only way I can write assertions on $model is to use its public interfaces.

```
$this->assertEquals($model->getName(), 'name');
```

What confuses me here is what exactly am I testing with that assertion? Am I testing that getName works properly or am I testing doSomething works properly?

In order for me to test doSomething, I have to assume that getName works. So how do I make sure that is the case?

Comment: Helpful to remember: You always want to assert that the output is what you expected given a specific input. In this case I would use an assertInstanceOf, but this is obviously just a trivial example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I would test that I got an instance of `Model` returned.  And then using the public accessors or [`assertAttributeEquals`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals) to check that the properties of the object were correct.  This does test the getters of the model, however the object having certain properties is what you are expecting to happen.

Though as your class is both creating the object and modifying it.  I would change the method to take a `Model` as an argument.  This way in my test I can create a `mockModel` and make sure that any public setters are called with the proper arguments.  Doing this, I don't have to worry about any of the logic that `Model` has for properties that get set.

For Example:

Test Function:

```
public function testDoSomething() {
    $mockModel = $this->getMock('Model');

    $mockModel->expects($this->once())
              ->method('foo')
              ->with('some argument');

    $mockModel->expects($this->once())
              ->method('bar')
              ->with('some other argument');

    $sut = new SUT();

    $sut->doSomething($mockModel);
}
```

Your function `doSomething` only needs to become this:

```
public function doSomething(Model $model) {
   /** Do stuff with private methods **/
}
```

Now you are able to make sure that properties of `Model` are set with the proper values and not depending on the logic that may or may not exist in the class.   You are also helping to specify the contract that `Model` needs to fill.  Any new methods that you are depending on will come out in your integration / system tests.

Comment: This is a great answer. My follow up question would be: The methods foo and bar would probably be tested in another unit test, which leads to the same question: If foo and bar are methods that set some attributes in model, how do we test them? Do we have to assume getters work?

Comment: I test them using any public methods that exist of accessing the data.  I am not going to assume that the getters work.  I am going to use the set method to assign a known value and use the getter to verify that a proper value was set (There may be some sort of formatting/typecasting) that occurs and I will check for that.  I will have one test that checks them both.  I get both methods checked in the same test.

Comment: That sounds like a practical way of doing about it. All the stuff I read about unit testing encourages you to keep mocking out objects and methods until you are testing only ONE thing. But when it comes down to getters and setters there is really no choice but to test them together, is that right?

Comment: That is kind of the way that I see it.  The get/set is one behavior and that is what I am testing.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract with doSomething() is, that it has to return an object of type "Model". Your contract is not getName() working on a returned object. As result, test $model to be of correct type:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('Model', $model);
```

Documentation: [PHPUnit -> assertInstanceOf()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertInstanceOf%20PHPUnit-%3EassertInstanceOf().)

---

As a hint, "[i]deally, each test case is independent from the others" [2014-10-21 wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

So, in your test_doSomethingTest*(), you are supposed to test only what happens within that function. Check for return type, and whatever happens withing that function. Testing getName() should be in it's own test_getName*().